# backpack-for-laravel How to change the field attribute upon ajax selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a field in my crud

```
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name'      => 'transaction_type',
            'label'     => 'Transaction Type',
            'type'      => 'select2',
            'entity'    => 'transactionType',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model'     => 'App\Models\TransactionType',
            'attributes' => [
                'required' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        $this->crud->addField([
            'name'      => 'developer_id',
            'label'     => 'Developer',
            'type'      => 'select2',
            'entity'    => 'developer',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model'     => 'App\Models\Developer',
        ]);
```

I want to make the attribute required for developer_id to true since it is false by default. I know how to make it false by using this code below

```
$this->crud->modifyField('developer_id',['attributes' => [
      'required' => true,
]]);
```

The question now is, how do I make `developer_id` to `'required' => true` upon selecting an option in `transaction_type`?
What I've got so far is to put `'data_source' => url("admin/api/devrequirement")'` inside the addfield of transaction_type. so it would look like this

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'name'      => 'transaction_type',
            'label'     => 'Transaction Type',
            'type'      => 'select2',
            'entity'    => 'transactionType',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'data_source' => url("admin/api/devrequirement"), //i added it here
            'model'     => 'App\Models\TransactionType',
            'attributes' => [
                'required' => true,
            ],
        ]);
```

and then put a route inside my custom routes:
`Route::get('/api/devrequirement', 'SaleCrudController@setDevRequirement');`
and inside that function is:

```
public function setDevRequirement(Request $request)
    {
        $form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');
        $transaction_type = $form['transaction_type'];
        if($transaction_type == 3) //if transaction type is equal to a specific value then required attribute of developer_id should be true
        {
            $this->crud->modifyField('developer_id',['attributes' => [
                'required' => true,
            ]]);
        }
    }
```

But it doesnt do anything. it didnt put red asterisk on my Developer field nor asking for validation. I'm having a hard time about laravel backpack and how to manipulate ajax with it.

Comment: i did also to make custom fields and make a jquery inside that will fire up ajax when clicking the specific value. however, it reads the function, it even fired up my echo inside the function but it didnt read modifyField

`public function setDevAndProjectRequired(Request $request)
    {
        $this->crud->modifyField('developer_id',['attributes' => [
                'required' => true,
            ]]);
        echo "being fired";
    }`

Comment: pls help @tabacitu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, i just make custom field and put some js manipulation in there